# jquery selector id in loaded div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'm new to Jquery and I want to select ID in loaded div

My HTML page has div tag like this

```
  <div class="widget-body" id="customer_details_div">
```

when document ready i loaded HTML page in to this div tag

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#customer_details_div").load("button.html");
});
```

My loaded button.html HTML like this

```
<div align="right">
    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info" id="edit_btn"><h3>Edit</h3></button>
</div>
```

so i need to write jquery function of on click button ,I wrote like this

```
$("#edit_btn").click(function (event) {
    alert("clicked"));     
});
```

but it's isn't work please help me to do this